# memory leak in view struct

Tags: swift, swiftui, memory-leaks

For some reason the following code causes a memory leak and I can't figure out why. If I comment out the contents of the onEditingChanged callback in TableElement there is no leak, if I remove the data binding altogether there is no leak, and if I remove the viewModel and instead just declare mapData as a state in ContentView there is no leak, but that isn't a viable solution for my actual code.

What could be causing this memory leak?

Here's my model:

```
class EditFuelLevelViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var mapData: [[Float]] = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
}
```

And here's my view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private struct TableElement: View {
        @Binding var data: Float
        @State private var text: String

        init(data: Binding<Float>) {
            self._data = data
            self.text = String(data.wrappedValue)
        }

        var body: some View {
            TextField(
                "Enter Value",
                text: $text,
                onEditingChanged: { editing in
                    if !editing {
                        data = Float(text) ?? 0
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }

    @StateObject var viewModel: EditFuelLevelViewModel = EditFuelLevelViewModel()
    @State var text = ""

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
                .onReceive(timer) { test in
                    text = String(test.hashValue)
                }
            TableElement(data: $viewModel.mapData[0][0])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try one of the [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TableElement.init` has an issue. It may be the cause of your leaks.

You should use the State initializer to initialize your State

```swift
self._text = State(initialValue: String(data.wrappedValue))
```

Comment: Is this a general rule or in reference to this specific situation? Also, I tried this and am still having the same problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that your Timer causes the memoryLeak
did you try to directly put

```
.onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { test in
                    text = String(test.hashValue)
                }
```

or

```
onEditingChanged: { [weak self] editing in
guard let self = self else { return }
                    if !editing {
                        data = Float(self.text) ?? 0
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The timer is just there to illustrate the problem. It'll still leak without the timer if you cause the view to refresh manually. As to your second idea, that was my first thought too but weak self can only be used when capturing a class, not a struct